# In △ABC, median AM = 17, altitude AD = 15 and the circum-radius R = 10. Find BC^2

Tags: geometry, triangles

Question is as per title.

Here is a sketch that I made :

[image: sketch]

By Pythagorean theorem , DM is 8.
Now how can I calculate BD and MC?
I still haven't found a way to utilize the information that the circum-radius is 10.
(I have drawn circum-circle inside but it may be outside)

Any hints are apreciated.
(This is not class-homework , I'm solving sample questions for a competitive exam )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This solution is due to r9m's insight given on the chat. But since he does not want to give an answer, I am giving his wonderful geometric solution*:

[image]

$E$ is the perpendicular on $AD$ from $O$. We can show by side-side-side criteria that triangles $OMB$ and $OMC$ are congruent, hence $\angle OMC =90^{\circ}$. So $OE=MD=\sqrt{17^2-15^2}=8$, and $OM=ED=AD-AE=15-\sqrt{10^2-8^2}=9$. Thus, $BC^2=4BM^2=4(10^2-9^2)=76$.

---

*My original ugly solution:*

Note that:
$$2A=\frac{abc}{2R}=ah$$

Substituing the values gives, $bc=300$. Since, $2A=bc\cdot\sin A$, so $2bc\cos A=600\sqrt{1-(\frac{A}{150})^2}=600\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{400}}$.

Now by Apollonius Theroem, $578+\frac{a^2}2=b^2+c^2$. Thus by cosine rule, $600\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{400}}=578-\frac{a^2}2$. Squaring will give us a quadratic in $a^2$, which you can solve to get the answer.

Comment: I understand you until the Apollonius theorem. But how do you use the cosine rule afterwards ? Further how is that a quadratic equation ?

Comment: @AGoogler First of all, I admit this is a truly ugly solution, I will think of a better one if I can. So the cosine rule states that, $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A$. Now we have $b^2+c^2$ and $2bc\cos A$, substitute. And isnt it a quadratic equation in $a^2$, rearrange and square?

Comment: @AGoogler I have added on how to approach that quadratic if you have any problems. Is it OK for you? :)

Comment: I have added a geometrical solution that @r9m gave me on chat. I feel very ashamed seeing my solution infront of his.

Comment: Thanks for that ! I still have difficulties solving problem that require drawing additional lines and segments . Do you know any good book on geometry ? My exam is on 6 April so I really need a good book so that I can prepare for the exam .

Comment: @AGoogler I have the same exact problem myself, and due to which I have resort to crude algebraic techniques! Overall, I found this book quite good, https://www.flipkart.com/challenge-thrill-precollege-mathematics-4th/p/itmdyth3negn9hnt?pid=9788122409802 . Its contains all topics in precalc, including geometry, and starts from the basics and gradually raises level until you are ready for olympiad-level problems. But I think its a bit late now.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation . I'll try to read its geometry section. By the way , are you in 10th std currently  ?

Comment: @AGoogler Tommorow is my first day in 9th :)

Comment: Wow! You're not even in 9th yet you can solve all these hard questions , how so?

Comment: @AGoogler I just like maths, so I study it. Class [and grades] has nothing to do with how good you are. And if you think I am really intellegent, look at this, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/117002/balarka-sen .

Comment: @Sawarnik Did you appeared for RMO. If yes How much was the score?

Comment: @Ajay I haven't given the RMO yet. What about you?

Comment: Yep not selected just got one question?

Answer (score 0):

It was so simple I solved it in off period in school. You just need to drop perpendiculars some construction and it's over.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: How did your exams go? Googler is in the top 5!

Comment: 160 I failed Science sucked.

Comment: Oh :( You were so promising.

Comment: Yep bad luck. I have no right to say it now coz I failed. I anyway wanted to join BANSAL but dad said try this out as its near my home.